# angularjs javascript - easy way to convert html webpage to pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf-conversion

Is there an easy way to convert and view as pdf from my html webpage  in angularjs

example html:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" style="font-size: 12px">

    <tr>
        <th align="left">Qty</th>
        <th align="left">Item</th>
        <th align="center">Description</th>
        <th align="center">Rate</th>
        <th align="center">Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <td align="left">{{item.qtyToOrder}}</td>
        <td align="left">{{item.ItemCode}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{item.Desc}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{item.price}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{item.qtyToOrder * item.price}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no really easy way.  You might want to create an api perhaps with phantomjs.

Comment: anything easy with jquery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this jquery code actually works amazing!

http://jsfiddle.net/NishitDhakar/ugD5L/

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
    // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
    source = $('#customers')[0];

    // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
    // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
    // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
    // (class, of compound) at this time.
    specialElementHandlers = {
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 10,
        width: 700
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
        //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

UPDATE:  I actually see jspdf is limited.  selectpdf has a free nuget package you can install which seems to work well but is limited to 5 pages at a time.  so if you need more than that, you can buy the api.

Comment: this is only doing a great job exporting my tables nicely.  when i embed images in my tables it loses the image.  any ideas how to ask the author a question or how to crack the pdfjs.js code?